# "Uncaught ReferenceError: AutoResize is not defined"

Tags: javascript

What follows is my Javascript document, that runs in `$(document).ready()`. The Javascript is loaded from the footer of my site. For the purposes of simplification, I've put `[...]` in place of irrelevant code.

```
// When the document is ready, run the display scripts
$(document).ready(function() {

// Define the frame height functions
function getDocHeight(doc) {
    [...]
}
document.domain = 'mysite.com';

function resizeIframe() {setIframeHeight('date-price-book');}

function setIframeHeight(ifrm) {
    [...]
}

function AutoResize() {
    resizeIframe();
    resizeIframe();
    setTimeout("AutoResize()", 500);
}

AutoResize();

[... more Javascript code...]
```

When I run the page, I get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: AutoResize() is not defined`.

I can stop this error from occurring by commenting out the line `AutoResize();` (final line in my example code above). But why is this error being thrown? Surely the AutoResize() function has just been defined in the lines immediately above it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `setTimeout(AutoResize, 500)` is better, and possibly will fix your issue to boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setTimeout("AutoResize()", 500);
```

When the setTimeout above is executed, it evalutayes the string in global scope. AutoResize() is hidden inside the closure so it is not found.

Assign a reference to the function by using the name.

```
setTimeout(AutoResize, 500);
```

other option is a closure

```
setTimeout(function() { AutoResize(); }, 500);
```

You would use the closure method if you want to send a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're defining `AutoResize` inside the `$(document).ready(function () { ... } );` closure, it's not available globally (which is nice).

When you use a string instead of a function reference when calling `setTimeout` (which is bad), there is an assumption that the function call that the string will resolve to is globally available (because `setTimeout` runs in `window`/global scope).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure. It works when I try this part.

```
function AutoResize(){      
    console.log('test');
    setTimeout('AutoResize()',1000);
}
AutoResize();
```

Maybe it's somewhere else that something is going wrong.

Comment: Ahh you got me. I should be the one asking questions about programming. But stackoverflow won't let me because they think I'm too stupid to ask questions. But they think I'm smart enough to answer questions. So that's a good thing.